# QuickFix/J not reading logon response and initiating a new logon request continuously

Tags: quickfixj

I am using Quickfix/J version 2.3.0. The project is running fine on an environment but having the following issue on another one:

- Session connected and securities lists are received
- Heart beats are exchanged normally
- For one of the heartbeats, no reply, a TEST request is sent
- Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for heartbeat
- Logon is sent at 8:53:48.656
- Logon response is received at 08:53:48.773
- In the events log: 08:53:59: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for logon response
- New logon request initiated at 08:54:18.656
- Same behavior is repeated for 25 minutes
- During these 25 minutes, in the event log, optionnally we can see one of the following messages: 08:55:48: Disconnecting: Received logon response before sending request
  09:01:49: Disconnecting: Encountered END_OF_STREAM
  09:05:49: Received logon
  09:06:04: Sent test request TEST
  09:06:31: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for heartbeat
- After this, we are connected normally, we receive status of securities and market data then once done 09:18:19: Sent test request TEST
  09:18:46: Disconnecting: Timed out waiting for heartbeat
  And the same scenario above of continuous logon is faced again
- After the scenario is faced again, we can see new kind of errors in the event log:

20230530-09:19:33: quickfix.SessionException Logon state is not valid for message
(MsgType=y)
20230530-09:19:33: Already disconnected: Verifying message failed: quickfix.SessionException: Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=y)
20230530-09:19:33: quickfix.SessionException Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=y)
20230530-09:19:33: Already disconnected: Verifying message failed: quickfix.SessionException: Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=y)
20230530-09:19:33: quickfix.SessionException Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=y)
20230530-09:19:33: Already disconnected: Verifying message failed: quickfix.SessionException: Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=y)
20230530-09:19:33: quickfix.SessionException Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=f)

- After few minutes, we are connected again and everything goes back to normal

This situation is faced during multiple days, and it is not clear how to fix it, especially that the issue is not seen on other servers.

FIX configuration:

[default]
ConnectionType=initiator
ReconnectInterval=30
FileStorePath=logs/fix
FileLogPath=logs/fix
StartTime=00:00:00
StartDay=Sun
EndTime=23:59:59
EndDay=Sat
SocketConnectHost=****

[SESSION]
BeginString=FIX.4.4
SenderCompID=****
TargetCompID=****
HeartBtInt=30
ResetOnLogon=Y
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=FIX44.xml
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateUnorderedGroupFields=N
SocketConnectHost=****
SocketConnectPort=****
CheckLatency=N

SocketUseSSL=Y
CipherSuites=TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
SocketKeyStore=****
SocketKeyStorePassword=****
KeyStoreType=PKCS12
EnabledProtocols=TLSv1

Comment: What do you mean by "not seen on other servers"? Can you move your application to one of the other servers to check if the problem persists? In general the problem is most likely either in your application code or network. What do you do in your fromApp() method?

Comment: i mean that the same code works fine with the FIX gateway test but has this issue when the same app is connected to the prod FIX gateway. I dont think it is a network issue because the gateway is sending back a response for our logon request but it is ignored by the quickfix lib

Comment: 1. Does the test gateway receive the same amount of data as the prod gateway? 2. Do you start the app on the same machine regardless of if you connect to prod or test? 3. There are other kind of network issues apart from "connection refused" that could play a role. 4. You still haven't shown fromApp() code. My guess is that your app is pretty loaded with messages (or somehow hangs) and hence cannot process the incoming messages in time. 5. Are you able to take some thread dumps next time this happens? When your app is in one of these reconnect/timeout loops.

Comment: I think i may have discovered the issue, its mainly on the fromAdmin() not fromApp since we are talking about the logon process right? actually in the fromAdmin() i am firing an API call which is timing out, maybe this delay is causing the logon responses of the gateway to be ignored. I will do the call of api in asycn mode and see if the issue will be resolved. Will keep you updated. Thank you

Comment: It is not clear from the information you provided if the behaviour is triggered by logon or an app message. I am only shooting in the dark. But if you found something suspicious in fromAdmin then this might be the problem.

Comment: I am monitoring since 30min and so far the issue did not occur, we only have multiple reconnections after heart beat time outs and TEST requests. However i can still see few messages like: Verifying message failed: quickfix.SessionException: Logon state is not valid for message (MsgType=W). Are these harmful?

Comment: Could be a similar issue as the timed out API call. FromApp doesn't contain any DB calls, REST calls or other stuff that could block? Best would be if you could edit your question with the content of your fromApp/fromAdmin/toApp/toAdmin callbacks. But it could also be a network issue still. Problems with MTU/MSS, asymmetric routing, ... what does the other side have in their logs? In short those "is not valid for message" mean that you received messages while not being logged on, I.e. they probably queued up on your side and reach the engine too late.

Comment: The FromApp message is not currently treated in async mode, but its working fine, of course we have a risk of time out (DB/API) which will cause a loss of FIX messages, so we will try in the future to use a queue for the received FIX message so that we can prevent any loss of message. The logon issue was solved by using a new thread for launching api call. As for the "Logon state is not valid for message", i will ignore it for now as it is not common. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by running the REST API call that was made inside the  fromAdmin() in a separate thread to prevent loss of logon messages in case the REST API call takes some time to finish.